# Packet loss between windows guest and Ubuntu 14.04 host

Tags: ubuntu, networking, performance, kvm-virtualization

We are seeing packet loss between one of our Ubuntu 14.04 hosts and a KVM guest running Windows 2008 R2. The loss only shows up at high loads. Similarly loaded machines running 12.04 do not exhibit this behavior. Furthermore host to guest ping times are more erratic and on average take longer on 14.04. 
Ex:

on 12.04:

```
85 packets transmitted, 85 received, 0% packet loss, time 83999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.081/0.248/2.533/0.384 ms
```

on 14.04:

```
87 packets transmitted, 87 received, 0% packet loss, time 86013ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.088/1.109/9.776/1.916 ms
```

We thought this bug report:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1346917

Might explain this but after disabling KSM we have seen little improvement.

Any ideas? The Ubuntu kernel version is:

```
 3.13.0-39-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: High loads on the Ubuntu host, or high loads on the Windows guest? Is the Ubuntu host virtualized?

Comment: Both, the load is triggered by a large network burst directed at the host, the host does some processing and flings the transformed data at the guest. The host is on metal. Loss on host is negligible (despite higher ingress).

Comment: CPU loads, or network load? Have any hard numbers?

Comment: A bit more information: the load is actually not that high. CPU is at around 30% on the host, 8Mbit/s from linux to the windows guest, maybe 20Mb/s from windows to linux. To be more precise the traffic is between a LXC container and a Windows guest. As soon as LXC starts sending UDP to the Windows guest at about 8Mbit/s we see continuous increments in the drop counters reported by ifconfig.

Comment: Simple questions first: Are you using VirtIO? Have you updated the Windows VirtIO drivers?